# Lucene.net search doesn't return names

Tags: lucene.net

I am using `WhitespaceAnalyzer` to index some values.

```
document.AddField("transcript", <transcript value>, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.ANALYZED);
```

and do a search like follows

```
booleanMiniQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("transcript", <search value>)), rule);
```

when  contains some names like *baileys* OR *bailey* doing search for that doesn't return any result.

Can any one tell what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Before you search for a term in Lucene, you need to analyze the string with the same analyzer that you indexed that text with (in this case *WhiteSpaceAnalyzer*).

I would recommend using the QueryParser to make this process a lot easier, for eample:

`var qParser = New QueryParsers.Classic.QueryParser(Version, "transcript", WhiteSpaceAnalyzer) var termQuery = qParser.parse(<search value>)
booleanMiniQuery.Add(termQuery, rule);`